# Расширение для браузера и require('xlsx')

Tags: javascript, html, chrome-extension, require

Пишу небольшое расширение для chrome, задача которого, по кнопке экспортировать данные из html-таблицы в Exel. Весь код работает корректно в IDE, но в браузере отказывается. Рассматривал разные варианты типа vite.js, но это все слишком сложно для меня пока, и выглядит громоздко для маленького расширения. Прошу подсказать как заставить работать require в браузере.
Ошибка возникает в 8 строке, где как раз require.

```js
const button = document.createElement('button');
const buttonName = document.createTextNode("Download");
button.setAttribute("data-v-65f872da", "");
button.classList.add("ws-switcher__item");
button.addEventListener('click', printData);
button.appendChild(buttonName);

var XLSX = require('xlsx');
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = "javascript";
script.src = "https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.19.0/package/dist/xlsx.full.min.js";
document.querySelector('head').append(script);

setInterval(scanTable, 1000);

function scanTable () {
    // console.log('scan...');
    if (document.querySelectorAll('.my-modal-window')) {
        if (document.querySelector("[data-v-5e0f4770]")) {
            document.querySelector(".ws-switcher").append(button);
            console.log('***button added');
        }
    }
}

function printData () {
    const list = document.querySelector("[data-v-5e0f4770]");
    const res = list.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr');
    let data = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i ++) {
        if (res[i].querySelector('.span--underline')) {
            let item = {};
            item.number = res[i].querySelector('.span--underline').innerHTML;
            item.sum = Number(res[i].querySelector('.td-sum-row div').innerHTML.replace(/ /g,''));
            data.push(item);
        }        
    }
    console.log(data);

    function collectData () {
        const worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(rows);
        const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, "Orders");

        XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(worksheet, [["number", "sum"]], { origin: "A1" });

        const max_width = data.reduce((w, r) => Math.max(w, r.name.length), 10);
        worksheet["!cols"] = [ { wch: max_width } ];

        XLSX.writeFile(workbook, "order.xlsx", { compression: true });
    }
    collectData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В браузере не доступны методы работы с файлами . Нужно написать сервер который будет общаться с расширением.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, вынести функцию collectData  в отдельный js-file и импортировать его?

Comment: В отдельную программу запускаемую отдельно или через транспорт

Comment: Протокол JSONP - это то, что мне нужно?